# Wordpress get post title from database using wpdb

Tags: wordpress

I need to get the post title for a specific post in Wordpress using a wpdb query.

I need something along the lines of:

```
$dbpost = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT ID FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE 
post_id='$post->ID'", 'post_title'));
```

I want to do this rather than use `get_the_title()` as I am using the `qtranslate` plugin and want the complete title string, rather than an individual language version. Hence why I want to get it from the database before `qtranslate` can filter it.

This should be pretty straightforward for anyone who knows the correct syntax to use for the wpdb query (which I don't).

TIA.

Comment: for others; typo in field name; post_id should be id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Test that:

```
$dbpost = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT post_title FROM $wpdb->posts WHERE ID = %d", $post->ID));
```

Comment: You have missing `"` after `%d`